# How to remove "Add to Source Control" button from the VS2022 status bar?

Tags: visual-studio, ide, customization, visual-studio-2022, ide-customization

Is there a way to remove the [image] button from the status bar in VS 2022? All the solutions I could find are for versions prior to VS 2022.

I don't use any kind of source control and having that button linger in the status bar is visually unpleasing/annoying, especially when it's sitting next to information that's useful.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I had to install Visual Commander from https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/ and then enable the example extensions which modifies the UI so that the source control button is not displayed anymore

Answer (score 0):

There is since a while ago an excellent Visual Studio extension that hides the button for you:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Sebazzz.RemovetheVisualStudioPublishbutton

Absolutely recommend it.